# In Python I'm trying to convert all files in directory from PDF to CSV, then edit csv with Pandas before saving to new folder

Tags: python, csv, converters, pathlib, tabula

I have a directory `C:/Users/Desktop/folder/`. I want to convert each file from a PDF to a CSV, make changes to the newly converted file using Pandas and NumpPy, then save it to a child directory

I have this working when it is just one file, but when adding code to get it working on all files in a directory, it doesn't work. Code, as is, does nothing. When I run it, it completes with nothing process and no errors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tabula
import glob
from pathlib import Path

files = glob.glob("C:/Users/Desktop/folder/*.pdf")
childfolder = Path("C:/Users/Desktop/folder/childfolder/")

for file in files:
    # convert PDF into CSV
    tabula.convert_into(file, "Convert.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')

    # read newly converted csv
    df = pd.read_csv("Convert.csv")

    # add empty row in 0th position
    df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns)
    df1 = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

    # name columns added
    df1.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: "Record"}, inplace = True)
    df1.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "Field"}, inplace = True)
    df1.rename(columns={ df.columns[2]: "FieldValue"}, inplace = True)
    df1.rename(columns={ df.columns[3]: "Reason"}, inplace = True)
    # df1.drop(df.columns[1], axis = 1)

    # drop empty rows to clean up 
    new_df = df1.dropna(how='any',subset = ['Record'])

    # output
    new_df.to_csv(ChildFolder)
```

How do I convert all files in a directory, make edits, then save them to a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `new_df.to_csv()` must be a filename, not a folder name. Join the filename to the folder name to get the output file.

```
new_df.to_csv(os.path.join(ChildFolder, file.replace(".pdf", ".csv"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. ```Convert.csv``` is being saved in ```.../folder/```.  It will process a few PDFs, convert them to CSVs, but they are all empty with the added headers only. Then stops after a few PDFs, giving the error: ```pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file``` There are columns in the input file. Do think it saving ```convert.csv``` each time is an issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with tabula, but I can't think of why it would work differently in a loop. Are you sure all the PDFs have tables that can be converted to CSV? I suspect there's just a problem with some of the PDFs.

Comment: Yes, I have double-checked. The process that creates the PDF has been used for years. It has been converted one at a time, though. I have run the script on each file that makes it through this script; it runs with no errors and converts each file just fine.